# "do-release-upgrade" - told to install all updates but I have just done that and still get the message?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

Logging in Ubuntu 18.04 I get offered the option of upgrading my release using `do-release-upgrade`.

When I try that I get:

```
foo@bar:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

So then I did a:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and try again but I get the same message.

Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Sholdn't it be `sudo do-release-upgrade` ?

Answer (score 6):

I solved it with:

```
sudo apt list --upgradable -a
```

and then installing manually those packages with the old `sudo apt-get install ...`.

Comment: I used this to get them installed `sudo apt list --upgradeable -a 2>/dev/null | sort | uniq | cut -d '/' -f 1 | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get install`

Answer (score 0):

This site, https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2020/08/03/linux-en-note-how-to-upgrade-to-new-release/, provides an easier comprehensive approach using the following:

> First, we need to update our current system.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade -y
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```
>
> After performing the above actions, we can proceed to the next step.
>
> ```
> sudo do-release-upgrade
> ```
>
> But this time usually reminds you that you need to reboot, so let's
> reboot.
>
> ```
> sudo reboot
> ```
>
> Upgrade after booting:
>
> ```
> sudo do-release-upgrade
> ```
>
> At this time, you usually need to wait patiently for a while, and then
> the system will automatically start updating.